# Consider including TAG "osmdroid"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I do not  yet have enough reputation to propose tags in questions.

Can someone with more reputation create a tag for [osmdroid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osmdroid), please?

It is a free, open source Android library that provides Tools / Views to interact with OpenStreetMap-Data. It is an alternative library to Google Maps API.

Comment: OSMDROID is not software that I had noticed before this post but a search just now suggests enough questions to justify the tag being created (which I cannot do from my iPhone).

Comment: The osmdroid tag now exists, but it needs a description

Comment: a free, open source Android library  that provides Tools / Views to interact with OpenStreetMap-Data.  It is an alternative library to Google Maps API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @EvilGenius:

> The osmdroid tag now exists